# `amp-list` documentation: what is the meaning of `<%host%>` URL prefix in the src attribute?

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

The `amp-list` item [doc](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list) shows an example with a `src` attribute prefixed with `<%host%>`.

I tried to search for an answer for the meaning of this but did not find anything.
This does not seem like an `AMP HTML URL Variable Substitution` as described at [link](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md).

Here goes the snippet I'm talking about -

```
<amp-list credentials="include"
    src="<%host%>/json/product.json?clientId=CLIENT_ID(myCookieId)">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    Your personal offer: ${{price}}
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

I saw this `<%host%>` prefix on other places in the documentation, was expecting to find some more information about it.

Comment: your domain - the source of `product.json`

Comment: Can you provide a link to example documentation with the markup? I bet the site is either using a templating engine that is supposed to replace `<%...%>` with other text, or its just meant to indicate "insert your own host name here".